# Laravel: Selecting all films where the condiction is in another table

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent

I have two models ("**Films**" and "**Tags**") related in a Many to Many relation.
I have therefore Three Tables: "**films**", "**tags**" and "**film_tag**"
EDITED:
I have belongsToMany relations in place like this:

**film.php**

```
public function tags()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag', 'film_tag');
}
```

tag.php

```
public function films()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Film');
}
```

I want to get a list of all films that have a tag. I am passing the variable "**$tag**" which contaings the slug of the tag.

In my Database I have this

```
Table TAGS:

id  Tag

1   BEST
```

Table FILMS:

```
id      Film
1       Fantomas
2       Minions
```

Table FILM_TAG

```
id      Film_id     Tag_id
1       1           1
2       2           1
```

So, one tag asigned to two films.

1- Using Laravel Eloquent I did this:

```
    if (isset($tag)) {
        $all_element = Film::whereHas('tags', function ($query) {
                $query->where('tag', $tag);
            })
            ->get();

    }
```

But I get the following error message:

> Undefined variable: tag

**QUESTIONS:**

- how do I "join" the tow tables in Eloquent?
- how could I make the variable recoffnized inside the query function?

2- Using normal laravel queries with DB I did this:

```
    if (isset($tag)) {
        $all_element = DB::table('films')
            ->join('film_tag', 'film_tag.film_id', '=', 'films.id')
            ->join('tags', 'tags.id', '=', 'film_tag.tag_id')
            ->select('films.*')
            ->where('tags.slug', '=', $tag)
            ->get();
    }
```

In this case I get just the first film repeated the number of times that this relation exist. In this case "Fantomas" two times. If I would have ten related films, I would get the first film repeated ten times.

In the other hand this variant do not give back a collection and therefore is difficult to manipulate the results (since all the methods are build to works with collections of objects)

3- I did a third solution which get the right solution: getting all films and then foreach

```
$all_element = Film::get();

if (isset($tag)) {
    $element_paused = array();
    foreach ($all_element as $element) {
        if (count($element->tags) > 0) {
            foreach ($element->tags as $gat) {
                if ($gat->slug === $tag) {
                    array_push($element_paused, $element);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    $all_element = $element_paused;
}
```

but this is a very SLOW solution, since I have more that 700 films in the Database

I would like to implement the first approach, which is very fast, but I get the repeated film all the time.
Any help to find the bug would be appreciated

Comment: you have used a pivot table. do your `tags` relation is `belongsToMany` ?? and when using a variable inside a function you have to use the variable to use it inside the function. `Film::whereHas('tags', function ($query) use($tag) {`

Comment: Yes, I have the belongstoMany. I have updated the question

Comment: Check out my answer.

Comment: Now I get not error, however, the solution does not bring any results back. I wanted to gget rid of the third solution (look at my question) because it has a big performance impact. But somehow i do not manage to get the list of the films under a tag

Comment: use `slug` instead of `tag`. check the updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using `belongsToMany` relationship this is the best approach to get all your films.

```
if (isset($tag)) {
    $all_element = Film::whereHas('tags', function ($query) use($tag) {
            $query->where('slug', $tag);
        })
        ->get();

}
```

Look you are missing the `use($tag)` portion for what you are getting `undefined variable: tag` error.

Answer (score 0):

> But I get the following error message:
>
> Undefined variable: tag

You should pass `$tag` to query function

```
if (isset($tag)) {
    $all_element = Film::whereHas('tags', function ($query) use($tag) {
            $query->where('tag', $tag);
        })
        ->get();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try it in this way and let me know what are you getting

```
$films=Film::with('tags') ->get() ;
foreach ($films as $film)
{
$film->tags->first()->Tag;
}
```